# Replacement of empty strings in data frame takes very long

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R with 11M rows and 46 columns. Some of the fields contain empty strings (""). I need to replace those empty strings with NAs because `write.dta` (in the `foreign` package) can't handle empty strings.

My for-loop, however, takes very long (around 15 minutes per column; sometimes R/ entire system crashes). I'm running RStudio (R 3.0.2) on a 8GB RAM Mac. Does anyone know of a faster way?

```
for (i in 1:46){

   if (length(which(myDF[,i]==""))!=0) {

    myDF[,i][which(myDF[,i]=="")]<-NA 

   }
}
```

Comment: `for`-loops in R are notorious slow. Avoid when possible. You can instead look at `apply`, `sapply`, `lapply`. Or see solution of @Zbynek.

Comment: @MrGumble not true.  Not true at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```
myDF[myDF==''] <- NA
```

Comment: Do you have a suggestion to make this work with data frames that have posix columns? I like your solution but it produces error "Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...): character string is not in a standard unambiguous format" and I would like to preserve data types.

Comment: @triSaratops I think you can not have empty string in POSIXlt column - `as.POSIXct('')` produces error. Could you please post example of your data?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `is.na<-` function:

```
is.na(myDF) <- myDF == ''
```